# Webkit Transform scaling issue

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Facing scaling issue, how to remove extra space between the two span elements.

I can't add extra tags as per requirement. within the span tag how to fix this issue.

```
span {
  -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0%;
}
```

**Before splitting span**

```
    <p style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; ">
        <span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000000; letter-spacing: 0pt; text-transform: none; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; word-spacing: 1.33pt; -webkit-transform: scale(0.7,1); -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -o-transform: rotate(0deg); text-shadow: none; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap ;width:auto;height:auto;">Keebler Zesta Saltine Crackers</span>
    </p>
```

*Screenshot before splitting span*

[image]

**After splitting span**

```
    <p style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; ">
        <span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000000; letter-spacing: 0pt; text-transform: none; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; word-spacing: 1.33pt; -webkit-transform: scale(0.7,1); -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -o-transform: rotate(0deg); text-shadow: none; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap ;width:auto;height:auto;">Keebler Zesta Saltine</span><span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000000; letter-spacing: 0pt; text-transform: none; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; word-spacing: 1.33pt; -webkit-transform: scale(0.7,1); -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -o-transform: rotate(0deg); text-shadow: none; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap ;width:auto;height:auto;"> Crackers</span>
    </p>
```

*Screenshot after splitting span*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale the container

```css
p {
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.7, 1);
     transform: scale(0.7, 1);
}
```

```html
    <p style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; ">
        <span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000000; letter-spacing: 0pt; text-transform: none; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; word-spacing: 1.33pt; text-shadow: none; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap ;width:auto;height:auto;">Keebler Zesta Saltine</span>
      <span style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000000; letter-spacing: 0pt; text-transform: none; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; word-spacing: 1.33pt;  text-shadow: none; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap ;width:auto;height:auto;"> Crackers</span>
    </p>
```

If you are only planning for 2 spans, you can align them using a global scale for the container, a scale for the second span, and setting the transform origin to the left so that the spacing between them doesn't change.

Note that the total scale of the second span is the combination of both transforms

```css
p {
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: scale(0.5, 1);
}
.test {
  transform: scale(2, 1);
  transform-origin: left center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Keebler Zesta Saltine</span>
  <span class="test">Crackers</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Splitting 2 span reason is to apply different scaling for each span within one paragraph element. If I apply to paragraph tag it will apply same to all spans. @vals Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS transforms doesn't affect the element's bounding box.

That's why during layouting the first span still has the same width like without `scale(0.7,1)`.

You can try setting an explicit `width` for example. Or do some negative `margin-right` magic.

Comment: If fixed content we can give margin right. But the contents are not fixed. Any way to make it dynamic using CSS3. @Christoph Thanks